# Vertical equivalence near an itemize

Tags: itemize, arrays

How can I put a long `\Updownarrow` along an `itemize` like on this picture?

[image: array with bullets and long vertical equivalence]

I did something with an `array` (following code) but bullets are missing :

```
\left\Updownarrow
\begin{array}{c}
    d=PGCD(a,b) \\
    a\mathbb{Z}+b\mathbb{Z}=d\mathbb{Z}\\
    (\forall q \in \mathbb{N}),\ (q\mid a) \wedge (q\mid b) \iff (q\mid d)
\end{array}
\right.
```

And here's the result:

[image: Just an array with a left \Updownarrow]

So does someone have an idea how could I put the bullets here like with an `\itemize`? (I already tried an `itemize` with a `\left\Updownarrow` but it totally messed up)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a column that auto-inserts these bullets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\DeclareMathOperator{\PGCD}{PGCD}
\begin{document}
$\left\Updownarrow
\begin{array}{>{\bullet}c@{\,}c}% replace \, by some other space to achieve your favorite spacing
&    d=\PGCD(a,b) \\
&    a\mathbb{Z}+b\mathbb{Z}=d\mathbb{Z}\\
&    (\forall q \in \mathbb{N}),\ (q\mid a) \wedge (q\mid b) \iff (q\mid d)
\end{array}
\right.$\bigskip

or\bigskip

$\left\Updownarrow
\begin{array}{>{\bullet}c@{\;}l}% 
&    d=\PGCD(a,b) \\
&    a\,\mathbb{Z}+b\,\mathbb{Z}=d\,\mathbb{Z}\\
&    (\forall q \in \mathbb{N}),\ (q\mid a) \wedge (q\mid b) \iff (q\mid d)
\end{array}
\right.$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I never saw an auto-insertion (`>{\bullet}c@{\,}c`) before, I'll read some docs about that.

Comment: @Enevevet This is documented in the manual of the (IMHO amazing) array package. The collcell package goes even a step further by allowing you to wrap the cell contents in a macro, but this is not needed here.

Answer (score 4):

You can add bullets in your `array` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\left\Updownarrow
\begin{array}{rc}
    \bullet & d=PGCD(a,b) \\
    \bullet & a\mathbb{Z}+b\mathbb{Z}=d\mathbb{Z}\\
    \bullet & (\forall q \in \mathbb{N}),\ (q\mid a) \wedge (q\mid b) \iff (q\mid d)
\end{array}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Effectively, that what I was looking for but Schrödinger's cat did the same with an autoinsertion for `\bullet`